# Show $\inf\{1/n: n \in \Bbb N \} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I know there's this post below

[Show that $\inf(\frac{1}{n})=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916352/show-that-inf-frac1n-0)

But I want to try out slightly different proof to see if I actually understand the logic of such proofs.

Proof:

Let $S = \{1/n: n \in \Bbb N \}.$ We have $0 \le 1 \implies 0 \le \frac 1n$ meaning $0$ is a lower bound of $S$.

Now if we can find a number $x$ in $S$ s.t. $0 < x < y$ for all $y \in S$, we are done as, then, nothing in $S$ is a lower bound. To that end, we want some natural $n$ s.t. $x = \frac 1n < y$ meaning $n > \frac 1y.$ Note, $\lceil \frac 1y \rceil \ge \frac 1y$ implying $\lceil \frac 1y \rceil + 1 > \frac 1y$ and so we can let $n = \lceil \frac 1y \rceil + 1 $ which then gives us $x = \frac 1n = \frac{1}{ \lceil \frac 1y \rceil + 1}$. Now $\lceil \frac 1y \rceil \in \mathbb N \implies x \in S$. We also know $x < y$ because of the way we constructed $x \ \square$

I realize in formal proofs we wouldn't show the construction process. Instead we'd claim $x$ to be "bla" and show "bla" < $y$. I am not worried about the style and beauty, just wondering if the idea behind the proof makes sense. So, does the proof make sense? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: Why do you assert that $0\leqslant1\implies0\leqslant\frac1n$?

Comment: you have $1>0$ not $1>=0$

Comment: Makes quite a lot of sense...

Comment: $0≤ 1$ is true too ....

I suppose he divided by $n$ on both sides

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I divided both sides of $0 < 1$ by $n$ (although, I did state $0 \le 1$ which is a mistake).

Comment: No, this is not a mistake, $0≤ 1$ means $0 <1$ or $0=1$, which is true. It is usually better to write weak inequalities when you do not need strong inequalities (like here) since they pass to the limit.

Comment: But you should write "Since $0 ≤ 1$, by dividing both sides by $n$, we deduce that $0 ≤ \frac{1}{n}$. Because with the $\Rightarrow$ your are just indicating that the implication is true, not the premiss (i.e. $0≤ 1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach.

We know as you stated that $0$ is a lower bound for our set, we want to show that it is the Greatest Lower Bound.  This means that $\forall \epsilon>0$ we have $0+\epsilon$ is NOT a lower bound.  So pick an $\epsilon>0$ and then can you show that there must be $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$?  If this is true then we are done since $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary.